# Running a cmd based program hidden and remotly

Tags: cmd

I want to run photorec , within a cmd but remotely and to hide the cmd that starts when i open the program ...
SO i have all my files in a folder

Then i open a cmd window in that location and run 'start photorec_win.exe'
But it open a new cmd window :( (the program)
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V647f.png)

My question is can i get that cmd (program) to show in the first cmd windows ? And for the porgram not to execute.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated <3

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: need to recover files of my wifes laptop because i believe she is cheating on me, She wont let me get near to her laptop. I know its not right but I dont want to carry on with her if this is the case.